# Finding the number of possible ways to 'paint' a geometry

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, coloring

Problem:

> Find the number of possible ways to paint $n$ sectors of a disk with $n$ color brushes to differentiate all $n$ sectors. (i.e., you cannot paint an adjoining sector with the same color)
>   [image]

It's simple labor when n is small, but I can't find a general way of solving this for any $n$
... Thanks in advance

Comment: The first sector you paint can be any colour. The second can be anything but the first colour. The third can be anything but the second and so on. This would give $n(n-1)^{n-1}$ if it was just a strip, and not a circle.

Comment: @Arthur, the last one can be any color but the next to last or first, i.e., $n (n - 1)^{n - 2} (n - 2)$ (or thereabouts, it isn't that simple either). But even that doesn't take into consideration that you can rotate the pattern...

Comment: @chanhee jeong What is the source of the problem? Was it a homework under 'polya's enumeration theory?'

Comment: Do rotations of a pattern count as different?

Answer (score 0):

We shall solve a (slightly) general problem: We find the number of circular sequences or necklaces (identical up to rotation) with $n$ elements and $k$ colors such that no two neighboring elements are equal (In a circular sequence, we consider first and last terms to be neighbors of each other).

---

**Lemma** Let $f(k,m)$ be the number of circular sequences (rotations are considered different) of length $m$ with entries from $\{1,2,\dots , k\}$ such that no two neighboring terms are equal is given by the recurrence relation, $$f(k,m)=(k-1)f(k,m-2)+(k-2)f(k,m-1)$$ and the initial conditions,
$f(k,1)=k, f(k,2)=k(k-1), f(k,3)=k(k-1)(k-2)$

- If $m-1$ th entry is same as the first entry: we can fill the last
  entry in $k-1$ ways and the initial part of the sequence of length
  $m-2$ in $f(k,m-2)$ ways as the $m-2$ th entry cannot be same as the
  first entry.
- If the $m-1$ th entry is not the first entry: we can fill the last
  entry in $k-2$ ways. The initial part of length $m-1$ can be filled
  in $f(k,m-1)$ ways.

Solving the recursion yields, $$f(k,m)=(-1)^{m+1}+(k-1)^m+k(-1)^m$$
when $m>3$ and $k>2$.

---

We shall consider the action of the group $\mathbb{Z}_n$ over the set of necklaces (as in the lemma). We shall use Burnside lemma to count the number of distinct (identical up to rotation) circular sequences. Let $|C(R_m)|$ be the number of necklaces fixed (that look identical to the start position) after $m$ rotations (say clockwise). For $m=1$, $|C(R_1)|=0$ as neighbors are distinct. For $m=2$ and $n$ is even, $|C(R_2)|=k(k-1)$ as the circular sequence is $2$-periodic (A circular sequence is said to be $p$-periodic if $a_i=a_{(i+p)\mod n} \quad \forall \, 0\le i\le n$ and $1\le p\le n-1$ is the smallest number with the property). If $n$ is odd, $|C(R_2)|=0$ as the sequence is $1$-periodic ($a_0=a_{n-1}$ and so on).

**To compute $|C(R_m)|$:** Let $n=qm+r$. The sequence has to repeat after $m$ rotations. The patch that repeats should have property stated in the lemma. If $r=0$, we get the simplest case. Here, $|C(R_m)|=f(k,m)$.

If $r\ne 0$, we have a cascading set of possibilities. Let $a_0,a_1,\dots a_{n-1}$ be the circular sequence 'read' clockwise from some arbitrary start point. We have $a_i=a_{(i+r)\mod n}\quad \forall \, 0\le i\le n-1$. (I might sound terse here. Please construct an example alongside as you read this). Hence, the sequence repeats after $r$ rotations if $r|n$.

We define a new function,
$$g(k,m,n):=
\begin{cases}
f(k,m) \quad \text{ if } m|n  \\
g(k,r,n) \quad \text{ if }m\nmid n
\end{cases}
$$
where $r$ is the remainder left when $m$ divides $n$ and $g(k,1,n)=0$

The required sum,
$$\frac{1}{|\mathbb{Z}_n|}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|C(R_i)|=\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{c=2}^{n} g(k,c,n) \right)$$

edit: except when $n=1$, there are $k$ different colorings.

The OEIS sequence is [here](http://oeis.org/A208535). The sequence for $k=n$ (one corresponding to the question above) is [here](http://oeis.org/A208533).